# Grant privileges to user on MySQL from java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to give to a user all privileges on a database to all the tables it has.

When I do it from Java, I get a syntax error when `this.ps.execute()` is called.

```
String setPrivileges = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ?.* TO ? @'localhost'";

this.ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(setPrivileges);
this.ps.setString(1, "dbTest");
this.ps.setString(2, "John");
    
this.ps.execute();
```

The error is:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException** near 'dbTest'.* TO 'John' @'%'

Comment: I believe this would be a limitation of prepared statements, in that you cannot use it to specify a dynamic field/table name (e.g. you cannot use them for `ORDER BY` clauses in this manner). In this one rare case, you can append **known** database tables to the query (or keep a list of allowed queries), but do not do that for user input. Overall, it's more likely there's a bit of a misdesign in your DB, as users should not really know anything about the database.

Comment: @Rogue is correct but you shouldn't be doing it from Java anyway - big security no-no

Comment: Both right, but I think it's only a syntax([quoting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-quoting)) problem... Try to hard code `dbTest.*` ... Try also `"?".*`

Comment: @xerx593 your approach would work for the username, but not for the `dbTest`. That will always be escaped as a value, and not a reference (which would use backticks ``` instead of `'` or `"`). In order for it to (maybe) work, you would need to enable `ANSI_QUOTES` for mysql, which has its own set of hassles/nightmares (e.g. strings can no longer be quoted with `"`). I believe the prepared statement would still just appropriately substitute it with `PRIVILEGES ON 'dbTest'.* ...` again, however.

Comment: You cannot use parameters for object names.